The same C code with GTK usage produces different results under different compilation conditions (on Makefile and not) without errors
We have this code in test.c file:

#include <gtk/gtk.h>

#define UNUSED(x) (void)(x)

static void activate(GtkApplication* app, gpointer user_data)
{
    GtkWidget* window;
    UNUSED(user_data);
    window = gtk_application_window_new(app);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "Window");
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 200, 200);
    gtk_window_set_resizable(GTK_WINDOW(window), FALSE);

    gtk_widget_show_all(window);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    GtkApplication* app;
    int status;

    app = gtk_application_new("org.gtk.example", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
    g_signal_connect(app, "activate", G_CALLBACK(activate), NULL);
    status = g_application_run(G_APPLICATION(app), argc, argv);
    g_object_unref(app);

    return status;
}

And we compile it with:
gcc -o app test.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0\`


with output like this: screenshot for example 1
And this is not resizable. So it is what we are looking for.
So if we put same code in main.c of project with structure like this:
proj struct
and Makefile:
CC = gcc

CFLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -Werror 
CPPFLAGS = -MMD -Isrc -Isrc/libdb -Isrc/libsqlite3 

SRCDIR = src
OBJDIR = obj/src
BINDIR = bin
OBJINT = obj/libint
OBJDB = obj/db
OBJSQLITE3 = obj/sqlite3
PKG-CONFIG = `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0`

TARGET = $(BINDIR)/todo

SRCS_INT = $(SRCDIR)/libint/interface.c $(SRCDIR)/libint/interface.h
SRCS_MAIN = $(SRCDIR)/todolist/main.c
SRCS_LIB_DB = $(SRCDIR)/libdb/db.c $(SRCDIR)/libdb/db.h 
SRCS_LIB_SQLITE3 = $(SRCDIR)/libsqlite3/sqlite3.c $(SRCDIR)/libsqlite3/sqlite3.h $(SRCDIR)/libsqlite3/sqlite3ext.h

OBJS_LIB_INT = $(OBJINT)/interface.o
OBJS_MAIN = $(OBJDIR)/main.o
OBJS_LIB_DB = $(OBJDB)/db.o
OBJS_LIB_SQLITE3 = $(OBJSQLITE3)/sqlite3.o

DEPS = $(OBJS_MAIN:.o=.d) $(OBJS_LIB_DB:.o=.d) $(OBJS_LIB_SQLITE3:.o=.d) $(OBJS_LIB_INT:.o=.d) 

# Rule for building the executable file
$(TARGET): $(OBJS_MAIN) $(OBJDB)/libdb.a $(OBJSQLITE3)/libsqlite3.a $(OBJINT)/libint.a
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@ -lm $(PKG-CONFIG)

# Rule for building the static libraries
$(OBJDB)/libdb.a: $(OBJS_LIB_DB)
    ar rcs $@ $^

$(OBJSQLITE3)/libsqlite3.a: $(OBJS_LIB_SQLITE3)
    ar rcs $@ $^

$(OBJINT)/libint.a: $(OBJS_LIB_INT)
    ar rcs $@ $^ 

# Rules for building object files
$(OBJS_MAIN): $(SRCS_MAIN)
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $< -o $@ $(PKG-CONFIG)

$(OBJS_LIB_DB): $(SRCS_LIB_DB)
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $< -o $@ 

$(OBJS_LIB_SQLITE3): $(SRCS_LIB_SQLITE3)
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $< -o $@ 

$(OBJS_LIB_INT): $(SRCS_INT)
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $< -o $@ $(PKG-CONFIG)

.PHONY: clean
clear:
    rm -f $(TARGET) $(OBJS_MAIN)  $(OBJS_LIB_DB) $(OBJS_LIB_SQLITE3) $(OBJS_LIB_INT)  obj/src/*.o obj/src/*.d obj/db/*.o \
    obj/db/*.d obj/db/*.a obj/sqlite3/*.o obj/sqlite3/*.d obj/sqlite3/*.a  obj/libint/*.o obj/libint/*.d obj/libint/*.a

-include $(DEPS)

run: $(TARGET)
    sudo ./$(TARGET)

it will give this result:
screenshot for example 2 and this is resizable. (Even with set of resizable FALSE)
I've tried to play with the Makefile but it didn't help. What is the problem? (https://imgur.com/a/Okfkehl same problem in simple Makefile)
Update: make output is:
gcc -c -Wall -Wextra -Werror  -MMD -Isrc -Isrc/libdb -Isrc/libsqlite3  src/todolist/main.c -o obj/src/main.o \`pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0\`

gcc -c -Wall -Wextra -Werror  -MMD -Isrc -Isrc/libdb -Isrc/libsqlite3  src/libdb/db.c -o obj/db/db.o
 
ar rcs obj/db/libdb.a obj/db/db.o

gcc -c -Wall -Wextra -Werror  -MMD -Isrc -Isrc/libdb -Isrc/libsqlite3  src/libsqlite3/sqlite3.c -o obj/sqlite3/sqlite3.o
 
ar rcs obj/sqlite3/libsqlite3.a obj/sqlite3/sqlite3.o

gcc -c -Wall -Wextra -Werror  -MMD -Isrc -Isrc/libdb -Isrc/libsqlite3  src/libint/interface.c -o obj/libint/interface.o \`pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0\`

ar rcs obj/libint/libint.a obj/libint/interface.o 

gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror  obj/src/main.o obj/db/libdb.a obj/sqlite3/libsqlite3.a obj/libint/libint.a -o bin/todo -lm \`pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0\`


Your Makefile is very complicated for your simple example. (I'm guessing your real code is more complex than your example.) But comparing the output from make to your command-line invocation of gcc should show any differences. You could [edit] your question to include the output from make and we can take a look.

Have you tried simplifying the makefile so it is a more apples to apples comparison? If you do that and it is the same you can add the additional parts one by one and see where it breaks.

@RetiredNinja https://imgur.com/a/Okfkehl here

The problem was in sudo command in run option of makefile. If we start gtk app with sudo it will be no resizable and it has different interface. I dont really know why but thats it.
